# Read-Only properties

Tags: swift, readonly

I need help with "read-only" in swift. I tried various ways, but simply couldn't figure out how to compile it without errors. Here's the question and what i thought of.

Create a read-only computed property named isEquilateral that checks to see whether all three sides of a triangle are the same length and returns true if they are and false if they are not.

```
var isEquilateral: Int {

}
```

Comment: That's a good start.  Now fill in the body.  Something like `return side1 == side2 && side2 == side3` where `side1`, `side2`, and `side3` are properties of your class/struct.  Oh, `isEquilateral` should be `Bool`, not `Int`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something like this? (as suggested by *@vacawama* in the comments)

```
struct Triangle {
    let edgeA: Int
    let edgeB: Int
    let edgeC: Int

    var isEquilateral: Bool {
        return (edgeA, edgeB) == (edgeB, edgeC)
    }
}
```

Let's test it

```
let triangle = Triangle(edgeA: 5, edgeB: 5, edgeC: 5)
triangle.isEquilateral // true
```

or

```
let triangle = Triangle(edgeA: 2, edgeB: 2, edgeC: 1)
triangle.isEquilateral // false
```

Comment: That is absolutely beautiful! Thank you. please tell me something. Why cant I just say return edgeA == edgeB ==edgeC?

Comment: @AllocSystems You're welcome. The syntax `edgeA == edgeB == edgeC` is __not__ valid in Swift. However if you want to avoid the tuples I used in my code you can write `edgeA == edgeB && edgeB == edgeC`.

Comment: Good answer. (Upvoted.) FWIW, I think the `edgeA == edgeB && edgeB == edgeC` syntax is preferable over the tuple syntax, as you can see what the code is doing at a glance. With the tuples, you have to carefully read what it is doing in order to reason about the logic.

Comment: I agree @Rob, I am seeing this again after many years and I find the tuple comparison harder to read.

Answer (score 161):

If you want a "read-only" stored property, use `private(set)`:

```
private(set) var isEquilateral = false
```

If it is a property calculated from other properties, then, yes, use computed property:

```
var isEquilateral: Bool {
    return a == b && b == c
}
```

---

For the sake of completeness, and probably needless to say, if it is a constant, you’d just use `let`:

```
let isEquilateral = true
```

Or

```
struct Triangle {
    let a: Double
    let b: Double
    let c: Double

    let isEquilateral: Bool

    init(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c

        isEquilateral = (a == b) && (b == c)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want a publicly exported property, for example from a framework, you can combine public and internal qualifiers as follows:

     `public internal(set)  var isEquilateral = false`

to allow other classes in the module to update the property or...

    `public private(set)  var isEquilateral = false`

If you only want the class implementation to update the property

Answer (score 11):

A read-only property is a property with `getter` but no `setter`. It is always used to return a value.

```
class ClassA {
    var one: Int {
        return 1
    }
    var two: Int {
        get { return 2 }
    }
    private(set) var three:Int = 3
    init() {
        one = 1//Cannot assign to property: 'one' is a get-only property
        two = 2//Cannot assign to property: 'two' is a get-only property
        three = 3//allowed to write
        print(one)//allowed to read
        print(two)//allowed to read
        print(three)//allowed to read
    }
}
class ClassB {
    init() {
        var a = ClassA()
        a.one = 1//Cannot assign to property: 'one' is a get-only property
        a.two = 2//Cannot assign to property: 'two' is a get-only property
        a.three = 3//Cannot assign to property: 'three' setter is inaccessible
        print(a.one)//allowed to read
        print(a.two)//allowed to read
        print(a.three)//allowed to read
    }
}
```